# Move directory to Grandpa directory and delete the parent directory

Tags: command-line, filesystem

Sometimes, we note that we have unused nested containers (directories) .

For example :

```
mkdir -p ~/grandpa/pa;
```

And `pa` directory is the only file existed on `grandpa`.

Hence, all files of `pa` should be moved to `grandpa`, then `pa` will be deleted.

My question is there is a built-in command line do such a mission:

i.e:

```
orphan  ~/grandpa/pa/*
```

or

```
fatherless ~/grandpa/pa/*
```

Comment: Good question. Happens to me if say I make a subdirectory to extract an archive and then the extraction software creates yet another subdirectory underneath that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use standard bash commands - `mv`, `rm`, etc - for example

```
mv ~/grandpa/pa/* ~/grandpa/ && rmdir ~/grandpa/pa/
```

This:

- uses `mv` to move the files in `~/grandpa/pa/*` to `~/grandpa/`
- uses `&&` so the rmdir command only if the `mv` exits successfully - `;` could be used..
- uses `rmdir` to remove the `pa` directory *if it is empty*.

**N.B.** tested on the directory structure - before:

```
$ tree ~/grandpa/
./grandpa/
|-- anotherfile.txt
`-- pa
    |-- child
    |   `-- file3.txt
    |-- file1.txt
    `-- file2.txt

2 directories, 4 files
```

after:

```
$ tree ~/grandpa/
./grandpa/
|-- anotherfile.txt
|-- child
|   `-- file3.txt
|-- file1.txt
`-- file2.txt

1 directory, 4 files
```